# Why does my network adapter have two IPv4 addresses in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, ipv4

I have a USB Ethernet adapter (TP-Link UE330). I assigned it a static IP address: 192.168.6 199. I was having trouble automatically detecting a device on the network. I investigated and discovered that Windows has assigned the network adapter a second IP address: a 'link-local' address
of the form 169.254.xxx.xxx as shown below. This has happened before.
Why does it happen and how do you fix it?
I've tried disabling the network adapter, restarting the computer and unplugging the network adapter. I'm not sure how I solved this problem previously.

```
C:\Users\don>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet (USB):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5091:426d:4b37:aa83%7
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.6.199
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.11.42
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Comment: It doesn’t have two ip addresses assigned to it.  169.254.11.42 isn’t a valid IPv4 address and is an indication that DHCP service doesn’t exist on the router/switch your connected to it.  Have you tried installing the driver from the product website? Your switch is 192.168.6.XXX, correct?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have it connected to a switch. It is directly connected to another device with a static IP address on the same subnet (it's 192.168.6).I'll download the latest drivers and give that a try.

Comment: 169.254.11.42 is totally valid. It is a link-local address and you can use it like any other IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with thanks to Ramhound.
I went to the TP-Link website which directed me to download the latest Realtek drivers. The drivers came as an installable exe, not a zip file with inf and dll files. I installed the drivers. I checked the network adapter. It still had the two IP addresses. I went to Device Manager, right-clicked on the network adapter and chose 'Uninstall device'. I then unplugged the USB network adapter and plugged it back it. I assigned it a static IP address. The second IP address hasn't appeared.